# Scipy Normaltest with multi-columns dataset

Tags: python, multivariate-testing, scipy.stats

I have a dataset with 100 rows and 21 columns where columns are the variables. I want to know if these variables came from a multivariate normal distribution.
Thus, I've used de Normaltest from Scipy library but I can't understand the results. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(2100).reshape(100,21)) # dataset (100x21)
k2, p = stats.normaltest(df)
```

In this example, p is a 21-array not a single value. Can anybody explain how to interpret this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `p[x]<0.05`, you may assume that values in column `x` are not normally distributed. Because with normality test, the null hypothesis is that population is normally distributed. With p<0.05, there is only less than 5% chance that we accept this hypothesis, which is statistically low.
Oppositely, it p[i]>0.5, the data are normally distributed. You can easily test it with a normal distribution:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,2100).reshape(100,21)) # dataset (100x21)
k2, p = stats.normaltest(df)
print (p)
```

The output is

```
    [0.97228661 0.49017509 0.97373345 0.97404468 0.03498392 0.61963074
 0.07712131 0.52632157 0.29887186 0.30822356 0.14416431 0.11015074
 0.81773481 0.52919266 0.81859869 0.24855451 0.16817784 0.0117747
 0.76860707 0.40384319 0.97038048]
```

with most of them larger than 0.05.

For testing of multivariate normality, you may try Henze-Zirkler test:

```
import pingouin as pg
normal, p = pg.multivariate_normality(df, alpha=.05)
```

where .05 is the significant value (you may change it if you want, it will not affect the p value you obtain.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. However, I don't see why the output is a 21-array and what does each element of the array represent?

Comment: This is because with ´stats.normaltest()´ you test if numbers in each column are distributed normally, so 21 p-values = 21 columns. I will my answer for a possible test of multivariate normality, could you try that and let me know? (I have somehow problem pip install the package)

Comment: If I've understanded correctly, _stats.normaltest()_ is not a multivariate normal test. It's a univariate normal test that can be used to test multiple variables toghether.

I've already try your test and this are my output:
Normal: `False`
p: `0.04797787634013723`

Comment: Yes, it should not have been used in your case. This is why you got this array of p-values from *stats.normaltest()*.

Comment: I have used the pingouin package and pg.multivariate_normality(x, $\alpha$). But I find that if the dimension of x is greater than 50, the function return nan as the p value. I don't know why.